# Not seeing Debug/Run Test in python test file in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've got VS Code version `1.33.1` and am experiencing something odd. When I open a test file I don't see the typical `Run Test | Debug Test` links above the test function as is seen [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). I do see the tests listed in the test explorer and I get no errors when running or discovering tests so the configuration seems to be ok from what I can tell.

[image]

Comment: make sure you have correctly configured interpreter for project.

Comment: Yes the interpreter is configured correctly.

Comment: If you can come up with a reliable producer then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.